# How could we loop again if we encounter some specific event?

Tags: javascript

I want to loop from start again if there a result of these loping are `Z` or `A`. I know that i have to some like `if(....) else(...)` function, but what i need for my case is looping from start again if meet some condition like above condition.

```js
var str = "";
var i = 0;
for(;i <= 10;i++){
  
  str += makeid();
  console.log(str);
}

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

For example, at the middle of looping, maybe at the the fourth looping, it got the result `Z` or `A`, it will loop from the first index again, and so on.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do instead of asking how to do something that is complicated to understand when we don't know what you are doing

Comment: @Camusensei i dont know how to do it, so instead, i asking this question... sorry

Comment: so if you loop over a Z or an A you want to have a never-ending loop?

Comment: You don't want a `Z` or an `A` to appear in your `text` if I understand correctly? Because in that case just remove these characters from `possible`

Comment: Why does your loop only does one iteration?

Comment: @tung i mean, if i meet some result like A or z, it will looping again from the start, there is no infinite looping since i produce a random character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop iterations depend on the condition that you are using in the for loop. If you wish to restart the loop again, then reset the flag to initial value.

`var i=0;` is the point from where your loop starts. `i<1` is your end point. If you wish to restart the loop in between, please reset the value of `i` back to `0`.

so, your loop should look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //some statements
    if(<some-condition>)
    {
        i=0; //it will restart your loop again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are looking for this to reset your loop if the character equals `Z` or `A`:

```
var str = "";
var i = 0;
for(;i <= 10;i++){
  var addChar = makeid();
  if(addChar == "Z" || addChar == "A"){
      i = 0;
  }
  str += addChar;
  console.log(str);
}

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```

Basically you add in a check to see if the character equals to Z or A with

```
if(addChar == "Z" || addChar == "A"){
      i = 0;
  }
```

And if it equals to one of these characters, you will reset `i` to 0, so the loop starts again.